# adding a quick order form in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to over ride the magento shopping cart options., i.e on each product when the user presses the order now / add to cart button , an html form will open in which the customer inputs name, address , email , contact number and qty, on submission the order will be placed by sending an email to the admin and the customer

i want to establish the same functionality as in: www.crorepati.pk

help will be appreciated.

regards,

Shehzad Rah

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this could help others:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quick-order-add-to-cart-by-sku.html

from

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/quick-order-add-to-cart-by-sku-magento-extension-free/

with a little know how you could edit this to display it everywhere you want.
If correctly installed you could also call the block directly like this:

```
<div><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('chapagain_quickorder/block_sidebar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?></div>
```